# Why is the currency modifier "C" returning '?' instead of '$' in C#?

Tags: c#

Why does the code below display '?' instead of '$'?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    float price = 29.56f;
    Console.WriteLine(price.ToString("c"));
}
```

The result is: `29,56 ?`

Comment: What’s your locale?

Comment: minor note: `float` is almost never a good choice for monetary values

Comment: I'm from Georgia, Caucasus.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's not an actual `?` character - that's a placeholder being printed in the console because the current console font doesn't have a glyph for whatever the local currency's currency symbol is (`System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol`).

If you always want US Dollars, then format using the `en-US` culture:

```
CultureInfo enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
String priceText = price.ToString( "C", enUS );
Console.WriteLine( priceText );
```

Don't use `en-US` for other cultures, even if they use Dollars too (e.g. Australian dollars), instead use their culture explicitly - so your program will still work if in the future the country changes their currency symbol, or if they have other formatting rules (e.g. a different decimal symbol)

```
CultureInfo australia = new CultureInfo("en-AU");
String priceText = price.ToString( "C", australia );
Console.WriteLine( priceText );
```

Additionally, you should not use IEEE-754 types when working with currency or monetary values because it’s imprecise by design. You should always use a fixed decimal type like `System.Decimal` or integer cents (though you can’t use `”C”` forest strings with integer cents)